# How come my constraints are not working? iOS

Tags: ios, nslayoutconstraint

I am just trying to set a width and a height constraint on my imgView. I have the following code:

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
imgView.center = self.view.center;
imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"favorites5-highlighted.png"];
imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
[self.view addSubview:imgView];

// width constraint
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[imgView(==100)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(imgView)]];

// height constraint
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[imgView(==100)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(imgView)]];
```

I end up getting this error: Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
I looked up SO and tried adding:

```
imgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
```

and

```
self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
```

EDIT:

I am just trying to set the width and height of the imageView to the desired properties. I first tried using

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10);
imgView.frame = rect;
```

but nothing changed

Comment: What change do you expect?

Comment: Assuming you add this code in `viewDidLoad`, you should move the last two lines into `viewDidAppear` to make it effective, where auto layout has finished its job and you can apply your changes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Two issues:

1. You do want:

   ```
   imgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
   ```

   You do not want:

   ```
   self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
   ```
2. Your attempt to set `center` is for naught, as when constraints are applied, this will be lost. Unfortunately, you don't define constraints to define the location of the image view. You might do that with the last two lines of the block below:

   ```
   UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
   //imgView.center = self.view.center;                                // this does nothing in auto layout
   imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"favorites5-highlighted.png"];
   imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
   imgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;             // add this line
   [self.view addSubview:imgView];

   NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(imgView);

   // width constraint

   [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[imgView(100)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

   // height constraint

   [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[imgView(100)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

   // center align

   [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:imgView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0 constant:0]];
   [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:imgView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1.0 constant:0]];
   ```